# Stubbing factory being used in resolve

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to unit test my states in an controller. What I want to do is stub out my `items` factory, since I have separate unit tests that cover that functionality. I'm having a hard time getting the `$injector` to actually inject the factory, but it seems like I'm letting the `$provider` know that I want to use my fake items object when it instantiates the controller. As a disclaimer I'm brand new to angular and would love some advice if my code looks bad.

Currently when I run the test I get the message:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /home.html
    No more request expected
        at $httpBackend (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1418:9)
        at n (node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:99:53)
        at node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:96:262
        at node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:131:20
        at m.$eval (node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:145:347)
        at m.$digest (node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:142:420)
        at Object.<anonymous> (spec/states/homeSpec.js:29:16)
```

It appears that my mocked items factory isn't being injected into the test. When I place a `console.log` line in the method I want to stub in the items factory I see that line being invoked.

The code I'm looking to test is as follows:

```
angular.module('todo', ['ui.router'])
// this is the factory i want to stub out...
.factory('items', ['$http', function($http){
  var itemsFactory = {};
  itemsFactory.getAll = function() {
    // ...specifically this method
  };
  return itemsFactory;
}])
.controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', 'items', function($scope, items) {
  // Do things
}])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'TodoCtrl',
      resolve: {
        items: ['items', function(items){
          // this is the invocation that i want to use my stubbed method
          return items.getAll();
        }]
      }
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

My test looks like this:

```
describe('home state', function() {

  var $rootScope, $state, $injector, state = 'home';
  var getAllStub = sinon.stub();
  var items = {
    getAll: getAllStub
  };

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('todo', function($provide) {
      $provide.value('items', items);
    });

    inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_) {
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      $state = _$state_;
      $injector = _$injector_;
    });
  });

  it('should resolve items', function() {
    getAllStub.returns('getAll');

    $state.go(state);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect($state.current.name).toBe(state);

    expect($injector.invoke($state.current.resolve.items)).toBe('findAll');
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your mocked factory is fine. You're getting an error because '/home.html' template is requested. Allowing real router in unit tests is a bad idea because it breaks the isolation and adds more moving parts. I personally consider `$stateProvider`, etc. stubs a better testing strategy. You just need to make sure that `$stateProvider.state` is called with expected configuration object as argument. The app can be tested with real router in integration/e2e tests if necessary.

Comment: I like that suggestion. I tried stubbing out `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider` in the same way I did with `items`, but unfortunately I'm still seeing the same error as above

Comment: I've posted an answer that explains that. Notice that you don't need to test it with `$state.go` in this case (and there will be no `$state` service at all in this spec).

Answer (score 0):

Allowing real router in unit tests is a bad idea because it breaks the isolation and adds more moving parts. I personally consider `$stateProvider`, etc. stubs a better testing strategy.

The order matters in config blocks, service providers should be mocked before they will be injected in other modules. If the original modules have `config` blocks that override mocked service providers, the modules should be stubbed:

```
  beforeAll(function () {
    angular.module('ui.router', []);
  });

  beforeEach(function () {
    var $stateProviderMock = {
      state: sinon.stub().returnsThis()
    };

    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.constant('$stateProvider', $stateProviderMock);
    });
    module('todo');
  });
```

You just need to make sure that `$stateProvider.state` is called with expected configuration objects an arguments:

```
  it('should define home state', function () {
    expect($stateProviderMock.state.callCount).to.equal(1);

    let [homeStateName, homeStateObj] = $stateProviderMock.state.getCall(0).args;

    expect(homeStateName).to.equal('home');
    expect(homeState).to.be.an('object');

    expect(homeState.resolve).to.be.an('object');
    expect(homeState.resolve.items).to.be.an('array');

    let resolvedItems = $injector.invoke(homeState.resolve.items);
    expect(items.getAll).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    expect(resolvedItems).to.equal('getAll');

    ...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still confused on where the entry point for the unit test is though. Previously I was using `$rootScope.$digest()` to initiate the resolution, but here I'm not sure what line I'm supposed to write to have the state executed.

Comment: This is the actual spec, the resolver is checked by `$injector.invoke`, you may trigger a digest afterwards f the resolver contains code that depends on digests. You don't need to execute the state at all here, just to check that the state is defined correctly with `$stateProvider`. The fact that `$state.go('home')` changes the state to 'home' was already tested by UI Router! If you need to make sure in addition that the units work fine together with no surprises, this is a task for integration/e2e Protractor tests.

Comment: Got it. One last thing, when I try to run the test I get an error on the first line `expect($stateProviderMock.state.callCount).to.equal(1);` because the callCount is still zero

Comment: I guess it is `undefined`, the spy should be `$stateProviderMock = {
  state: sinon.stub().returnsThis()
}` instead.

Comment: The problems isn't that its undefined, its that the `$stateProviderMock.state` isn't being invoked. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error that the call count equals 0 and not 1

Comment: I see, `todo` module depends on `ui.router`, and the mock is overridden by real `$state`. A good way to make it test-friendly is to break up the module, e.g. to move router configuration into `angular.module('todo.routing', [])`, main module should be `angular.module('todo', ['ui.router', 'todo.routing'])` ('ui.router', precedes 'todo.routing'). In this case `ui.router` file shouldn't be loaded in specs.

Comment: A quick workaround here is to just stub `ui.router`, see the update.