# Why isn't $injector finding $state in my unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

The following is my module and unit test set-up. When I try to set $`state`, `$injector.get("$state")` throws the always fun *Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state* error and I don't understand why.

```
angular.module("my-module", [
        //Third Party
        "ui.bootstrap",
        "ui.router",
        "toaster",
        "angular-loading-bar",
        "ngAnimate",
        "ngSanitize",
        "ApplicationInsightsModule",
        "pascalprecht.translate"
]);

describe("something descriptive and helpful", (): void => {
    // a bunch of other service variables....
    var $state: any;

    // I've tried with and without this line
    beforeEach(() => angular.module("ui.router")); 

    beforeEach(() => {

        angular.module("my-module");

        inject(($injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService): void => {
            // a bunch of other service variable assignments
            $state = $injector.get("$state");
        });
});
```

Comment: It should be also noticed that using a real router in specs is awkward. Stick to $stateProvider/$state mocks whenever possible.

Comment: @estus so, if I have to mock out my entire route configuration...what's the point of testing it? I'm practically rewriting the code at that point, right? Doesn't seem worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call

```
angular.mock.module("my-module")
```

to load the module.

Comment: I've tried doing just mock and the $state resolves, but then none of my ui-router states are available. `$state.go("home")` doesn't work, for example.

Comment: There isn't enough code to understand why that happens, but going to a state isn't what you typically do in a unit test. Usually, you test a controller, spy on the $state.go() service, and verify that (for example), after a form has been successfully submitted by the controller, it calls $state.go() to go to the correct state.

Comment: Sorry, I guess a little context would help. What I'm trying to do is unit test the configuration. So, when I call `$state.go("home")`, I can check `$state.current.name` or check that the `url == "\home"`. This is outside the scope of my question, so I accepted your answer. It's just part of the puzzle for me I've struggled with.

Answer (score 1):

The point of mocking `$stateProvider` and `$state` is to stub third-party services and test only your own code in isolation, thus reducing the number of moving parts.

It basically is

```
beforeEach(module("my-module", ($provide) => {
  $provide.factory('$state', ($q) => ({
    go: jasmine.createSpy().andCallFake(() => $q.resolve());
  }));
})); 

it('...', inject(($state, ...) => {
  ...
  expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('stateName');
});
```

At this point `ui.router` module isn't supposed to be loaded in tested modules because it will require additional stubbing.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38904472/3731501) for the explanation of how `$stateProvider` route configuration can be tested.