# defining current state in unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I've moved this 'reports' feature from a single module (called 'aam') into the core, so that other modules (such as 'bbc') can use it.

Now I'm rewriting the unit test(s).

The grunt error I'm getting is

```
should go state aam.reports with URL_NOT_SPECIFIED
     reports-state spec
     TypeError: 'null' is not an object 
     (evaluating 'BbpcConfiguration.getProperty(configProperty).then')
```

which indicates to me that $state is empty or not structured correctly.

Here is the report controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('com.ct.bbpcCore')
    .controller('reportController', ['$window', '$state', 'BbpcUserService', 'BbpcConfiguration', function ($window, $state, BbpcUserService,BbpcConfiguration) {
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            //Get url base on locale
            var reportUrl = "URL_NOT_SPECIFIED";

            var currentState = $state.current.name;
            var configProperty = "";
            var title = "";

            if (currentState.indexOf('aam.reports')) {
                configProperty = 'report.aam.link';
                title = "AAM.REPORT";
            };
            if (currentState.indexOf('bbc.reports')) {
                configProperty = 'report.bbc.link';
                title = "BBC.REPORT";
            };

            BbpcConfiguration.getProperty(configProperty).then(function(response) {
                if (response) {
                    var language = BbpcUserService.getLanguageCd() || "en_CA";
                    reportUrl = response[language] || reportUrl;
                }
                var spec = "width=" + $window.outerWidth + ", height=" + $window.outerHeight;
                $window.open(reportUrl, title, spec);
            });
        });
    }]);
}());
```

And here is report-controller.spec:

```
describe('reports-state spec', function() {

  'use strict';

  var $injector, $window, $rootScope,
      $state,  BbpcConfiguration, reportController, $controller, BbpcUserService;

  beforeEach(function() {

    module('com.ct.bbpcCore', function($provide) {
      $provide.value('BbpcConfiguration', BbpcConfiguration = {
        getProperty: function(key){
          if('report.aam.link' === key){
            return {
              "fr_CA": "https://eng-link",
              "en_CA": "https://fre-link"
            };
          }
          return null;
        }

      });
    });
    inject(function(_$injector_) {
      $injector = _$injector_;
      $window = $injector.get('$window');
      $state = $injector.get('$state');
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $controller =$injector.get('$controller');
      BbpcUserService =$injector.get('BbpcUserService');

    });
  });

   it('should go state aam.reports with URL_NOT_SPECIFIED', function() {
     $state.current = {'name': 'aam.reports' };

     spyOn($window, 'open').andCallFake(function(){});
     reportController = $controller('reportController', {'$window':$window, '$state':$state, 'BbpcUserService':BbpcUserService, 'reportLink':undefined});
     $state.go('aam.reports');
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect($state.current.name).toEqual('aam.reports');
    expect($window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('URL_NOT_SPECIFIED', 'AAM.REPORT', 'width=0, height=0');
  });
});
```

I tried simply adding the line **$state.current = {'name': 'aam.reports' };** in the 'it' block, but that's not what it's looking for.

Not sure how to debug unit tests. :P I can't use a console.log($state) to peek into it.

Comment: You shouldn't use real ui-router and $state in unit tests, this provides unnecessary moving parts and contradicts the purpose of unit testing. It has to be mocked entirely.

Comment: Not sure what that entails. I could pass a plain object in, like var mockState = {'current':{'name':'aam.reports'}} instead of $state.

Comment: For this spec, yes. In general, ui-router shouldn't be included in testing rig at all in order for it to not add moving parts (well, it can be physically included, but you need to stub $stateProvider and $state with `module` everywhere). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39170806/3731501 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38904472/3731501 for some ideas.

Comment: I don't get it. I'm trying this: mockState.current = { name : 'aam.reports' }; reportController = $controller('reportController', {'$window':$window, '$state':mockState...}); but I still  get undefined when evaluating.